# Integrate firebase remote config with Expo for iOS and Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-remote-config

I have checked numerous blogs and links to integrate Firebase with React Native Expo CLI. I Hope firebase was a success but how to continue with Remote config is still under research.

What I did till now-

```
A) Install the plugins & is visible under the package.json
   1. expo install @react-native-firebase/app 
   2. expo install @react-native-firebase/remote-config
B) Downloaded the google service JSON and plist files from the firebase project dashboard and added them to the app.json
C) I do not want to add separate iOS and Android folders for the same. Any option to do without that would be great.
D) People also suggested adding a config.js file that includes all info from the firebase project but its utilisation with remote config is still not clear
```

[image]
[image]